# Order by in for loop (SQL UDF)

Tags: sql, db2, user-defined-functions

I want to aggregate some rows using a SQL UDF. I want to first select the rows ordered by their id & then concatenate them in a comma separated column. I am having error on the order by clause in my function as it is inside a for loop. Is there any way to run this without removing the order by clause? My database is DB2

```
CREATE FUNCTION mySchema.getDates(recId INTEGER)
RETURNS VARCHAR(1024)
LANGUAGE SQL
    BEGIN ATOMIC
        DECLARE STR VARCHAR(1024);
        SET STR = '' ;
        LOOP1 : FOR ROW AS (select replace(char(myDate,EUR),'.','/') as myDate from myTable.BookingDates where recId=recId order by rec_crt-id)
        DO
            IF ROW.myDate IS NOT NULL THEN
                SET STR = STR || CAST ( ROW.myDate AS VARCHAR ( 20 ) ) || ', ' ;
            END IF ;
        END FOR;
    RETURN STR ;
END
```

> ```
> SQL State: 42601
> Vendor Code: -199
> Message: [SQL0199] Keyword ORDER not expected. Valid tokens: ) UNION EXCEPT. Cause . . . . . :   The keyword ORDER was not expected here.
> ```

Comment: ... Why do you want this as a delimited column?  Most types of formatting should be done at the application layer.  What version of DB2?  Also, SQL in general shouldn't be used with loops, because most of the engines weren't written to 'think' in those terms.  And `EUR` is an 'ambiguous' format, in that month/day may appear reversed (especially when using a 'standard' separator).  If I saw output from this, I'd probably assume USA formatted dates!  Note that this can be done through the use of a recursive CTE, though I'm not sure it should be...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Thanks for your detailed response, I agree with you on not using loops however it is a stupid requirement. The requirement is for a report where I have to show the dates for each row of data already returned by the query. I have used EUR to format dates in dd/MM/yyyy format (they are stored in database as yyyy/dd/MM as default).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse About recursion, I don't want to use recursion as it would be prone to errors. I don't know about the max level for a recursive sql statement also.

Comment: @DamienJoe, recursion wouldn't be any more error prone than any other method.  And there is effectively no limit to how deep you can go--it is not like a recursive function call placing things on the stack.  I just did a test of a 10,000,000 level recursive query and it worked fine.  There is nothing wrong with using looping if you have a fairly small number of rows.  However, if this solution is too slow, you might want to look at a recursive solution.

Comment: If `myDate` is actually a date/timestamp type (and that's a _terrible_ column name), it's not really stored in an ISO format.  If you have rows already, why can't you pull the dates from there - how is the rest of the data being displayed?

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to work:

```
where recId=recId
```

DB2 will not realize that you want one of these to be the function parameter and the other the column name. It will use the same one for both, having the effect of returning all rows.  You need to name your function parameter something different than the column name.

Other than that, code similar to the above works fine for me.

Are you new to writing functions?  One common mistake is having your SQL editor's statement delimiter set to `;`.  This will make it try to break up the function into statements, rather than sending the whole thing as a single command.  It will lead to lots of syntax errors such as above (Sorry if you know that already, but it took me awhile to figure that out!).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have renamed the parameters as you said. I am fairly new to SQL UDF, I have not used a delimiter for the 'select' satatement in above code. Are you refering to the delimiters for each statement?  Should I remove them all? Thanks for your understanding...

Comment: @DamienJoe, what program are you using to run this SQL code?  Somewhere in the settings, the program will let you specify a statement delimiter to separate statements.  Usually this is set to `;`.  You want to change that setting to something else.  Do not remove the semicolons from the function itself; those need to be sent to the database.